Transfer apps from another device to secondary user account on Samsung Galaxy S10 Ultra
I am a new user of the Samsung Galaxy S10 Ultra tablet. I created a 2nd user for my relative, but when I attempt to use Smart Switch to get her apps on her user, it says she is in guest mode.
How to transfer the apps to 2nd user?

A lot of tools like backup and restore were never adapted by Google to support a user different than the main/primary user. Seems like Smartswitch also was never adapted for a non-primary user.
